# Windows Shell: Invoke Context Menu entry

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, contextmenu

I am just doing some automating stuff and I'm a bit stuck. I have a program which does not offer any commandline operations (I want to start it with a script), but it offers a context menu in the windows explorer. If I could just "invoke" that or imitate a click or something like that, then the problem would be solved.

So I browsed the web for any solution - and found one: A short script for Powershell, which does exactly what I need.

```
$o = new-object -com Shell.Application
$folder = $o.NameSpace("c:\temp")
$file=$folder.ParseName("test")
$file.Verbs() | %{ if($_.Name -eq ' ... name of the context menu entry ...') { $_.DoIt() } }
```

There is only one problem with it: it only works with context menu entries, which are not in submenus. Unfortunately the needed context menu entry is in such submenu.

Does anybody have any suggestions?
I am open for any kind of solution:

- Edit the powershell script, so it works also with entries in submenu
- Edit the registry, so the entry is outside of the menu (I'm afraid this might not work, because it is implemented with a COM module in a DLL and I cannot change anything (?) )
- Any other solution: Thirdparty application ...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Search `hkey classes root` for "... name of the context menu entry ..." and you will find the `MUIVerb` registry setting, the key where that is will also have a command or GUID / DLL or some info we need.  Here is an example of what you might find when you search -   http://superuser.com/questions/686379/exe-with-parameter-in-registry-key/688697#688697   Report back the contents of the registry at your key and I can give better answer.

Comment: I could not find any entry for the context menu. I tried to find information with the tool "ShellExView" and i got the the location of the DLL. Its located in c:\...\NavShExt.dll. I also got the CLSID. I searched in the registry for this key, but I only could find out the version number, not any commands. I think I'm on the right way: I think it is an implementation of the IContextMenu interface ([Link to IContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776095(v=vs.85).aspx)). It offers "invoke" but its actually not really clear how to access these functions? With C++?

Comment: might be less wild goose chase if you tell us what app + command you are actually trying to run.  http://www.neuber.com/taskmanager/process/navshext.dll.html

Comment: Oh sorry. I didnt realize that i did not mention that. It is Norton Internet Security 2014. I want to run a scan.

Comment: Will this work ???   https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/v8278351_NIS_Retail_2012_en_us

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at WASP from codeplex?

http://wasp.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

The command line syntax for many subcommands can be found here.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no entry for the program :/

Answer (score 0):

you can use AutoHotKey to command based as well as gui based automation including clicking on a specific option.